# Jquery Count down Serversync issue

Tags: jquery, countdown

Hi I am trying to use [countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) with ServerSync, 
There are couple of questions related to this but none of them giving clear solution

my timer callback from server is c# code as below

```
 public JsonResult GetCurrentDateTime()
    {          
       var date = DateTime.UtcNow;
       return Json(data: date); 
    }

output is: Thu May 23 2013 10:23:00 GMT+0100(GMT Daylight Time)
```

and countdown calling script code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function serverTime() {
            var stime;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Auction/GetCurrentDateTime",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{}",
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    stime = new Date(parseInt(msg.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, ''))); 
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                }
            });

            return stime;
        }
 //Easter Standard Time or Eastern Daylgiht time
var daylightoffset = estTime.dst() ? -4 : -5;

$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: estTime,  timezone: daylightoffset, serverSync: serverTime, onExpiry: showAsClosed });
```

When i deploy this code to server and access in my local machine, and change my local machine datetime, counter down change the count down time...! I expected countdown timer depend on Server not local machine.

What mistake am i doing here! i have no clue. any idea will be appreciated.